# ICS HTTPCLI Free Exception

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

How can I properly free the component once i make it with a loop like this? If I free it like I do now I get some GETMEM.INC exception. I am coming from Indy so i don't really know ICS too much.

Thanks

```
  const
    URLs : array[0..3] of string =
    (
      'http://www.example.com',
      'http://www.example.com',
      'http://www.example.com',
      'http://www.example.com'
    ) ;

    var
      Output: array of TStringList;
      S: array of TMemoryStream;
      Async: array of TSslHttpCli;
    implementation

    procedure RequestDone(Sender: TObject; RqType: THttpRequest;
      ErrCode: Word);
    begin
        with Sender as TSSLHTTPCLI do  begin
          S[Tag].Position:=0;
          Output[Tag].LoadFromStream(S[Tag]);
        end;
      end;


    procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    var
    i:integer;
    begin
        for i := 0 to High(URLS) do begin
           S[i]:=TMemoryStream.Create;
           Output[i]:=TStringList.Create;
           Async[i]:=TSslHttpCli.Create(nil);
           Async[i].Tag:=i;
           Async[i].FollowRelocation:=true;
           Async[i].NoCache:=true;

           Async[i].SocketFamily:=sfAny;
           Async[i].OnRequestDone:=RequestDone;
           Async[i].RcvdStream:=S[i];
           Async[i].URL:= URLs[i];
           Async[i].MultiThreaded:=true;
           Async[i].GetASync;
        end;
    end;

    procedure TForm1.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
    var
    i:integer;
    begin
        for i := 0 to High(URLS) do begin
           Output[i].Free;
           Async[i].RcvdStream.Free;
           Async[i].Free; // << -- EXCEPTION
           //  S[i].Free;
        end;
    end;
```

Comment: Why don't you use a `TList` to hold the Http Clients? you could create the `TMemoryStream` e.g `Async[i].RcvdStream := TMemoryStream.Create` and you could free `RcvdStream` inside `RequestDone` without the need of parallel arrays. rethink your code and variable names. it's a mess.

Comment: @kobik Why don't you post it as answer? Hard to understand what you mean..

Comment: The [code sample](http://www.delphipages.com/forum/showthread.php?t=199517) in the link you initially provided in your previous Q does that rather well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never allocate any memory for `Result`, `Asynch`, or `S`. You need to `SetLength` on each of them before you can put anything into them (or take anything back out).

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
i:integer;
begin
  SetLength(Result, Length(URLS));
  SetLength(S, Length(URLS));
  SetLength(Asynch, Length(URLS));

  for i := 0 to High(URLS) do begin
    S[i]:=TMemoryStream.Create;
    Result[i]:=TStringList.Create;
    Async[i]:=TSslHttpCli.Create(nil);

    // etc.

  end;
end;
```

BTW, `Result` is a terrible name for a variable, especially one that's global in scope. It's the return value from a function that's automatically generated by the compiler, and use anywhere but in a function makes your code hard to read. See this, for instance:

```
var
  Result: string = '';

procedure AddToReslt(CharToAdd: Char);
begin
  // Many many lines of code
  // go in here. Maybe a few loops
  // of if statements.
  Result := Result + CharToAdd;
end;

function DoSomeMath: Integer;
begin
  // Some really complex numeric code, maybe
  // calculating the value of `pi` to the 900th
  // digit 
  Result := 2 * 2;
end;
```

Now quickly - remembering that each of them containss lots of code - which one is a function and which is a procedure?

Comment: Ofcourse the second one.. Procedure don't have result :) I should have named it Output. Not result hehe :)